# swift constraints with images on different size phones

Tags: swift

I have some problems with layout on small iPhone and the biggest one. It is always looks different, but I use constraints from Figma. This is how Figma looks like [image]

This is my result
[image]

This is code I do

```
private let welcomeImage: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        view.image = UIImage(named: "welcomeImage")
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var welcomeLabel: HMLabel = {
        let label = HMLabel()
        label.text = "Найди свою \nполовинку!"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.font = UIFont.hobbiesFont(style: .huge)
        return label
    }()
    
    private let heartButton: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.image = UIImage(named: "heartImage")
        return view
    }()


 private func addConstraints() {
        welcomeImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(79)
            make.width.height.equalTo(238)
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        }
        welcomeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(welcomeImage.snp.bottom).offset(32)
        }
        heartButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(welcomeLabel.snp.bottom).offset(32)
            make.width.height.equalTo(232)
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(170)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout is not going to magically size an image view to fit the aspect ratio of its image. It is up to you to know the aspect ratio of the image and to set the height and width of the image view in that proportion.

The image view itself, whatever its size, can make sure that the image, at least, is displayed at its correct aspect ratio. But *your* code (`view.contentMode = .scaleToFill`) is specifically telling it *not* to do that. You are telling the image view to distort the image to match the aspect ratio of the image view. So it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
private func addConstraints() {
    welcomeImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(79)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8) // Adjust the multiplier as needed
        make.height.equalTo(welcomeImage.snp.width).multipliedBy(238.0 / 238.0) // Use the actual image's aspect ratio
    }
    welcomeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalTo(welcomeImage.snp.bottom).offset(32)
    }
    heartButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalTo(welcomeLabel.snp.bottom).offset(32)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8) // Adjust the multiplier as needed
        make.height.equalTo(heartButton.snp.width).multipliedBy(232.0 / 232.0) // Use the actual image's aspect ratio
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(170)
    }
}
```

Adjust the multipliers as needed to achieve the desired size and aspect ratio for the images.

Comment: If you post code that relies on 3rd party libraries, you should at least mention what they are.

Comment: @HangarRash To be fair, this answer only uses SnapKit because the OP uses SnapKit.

Comment: @matt Is that what that is? Good to know. I hadn't noticed the OP also used `snp` until after I made my comment. Still seems worth mentioning though. Not everyone knows what every 3rd party library is. :)